# fbprophet/Prophet fit function aborts and restarts Anaconda/Spyder Python kernel

Tags: python, spyder, facebook-prophet, model-fitting

Hello and thanks for taking the time to read and consider this question....
I had this issue occur with no changes to my development environment.
I had been successfully running Prophet as recently as last week.
For testing, I have a 24 row dataframe called ads_mod. The first two rows are:
[image]

When the process gets to the Prophet modeling section of my code, the following occurs:

```
m = Prophet(interval_width=interval_width)
This executed, and I could see the object instantiated in the Spyder(IDE) Variable Explorer
```

```
m.add_seasonality(name='hourly', period=1, fourier_order=30) 
This executed
```

```
m.fit(ads_mod)   
This restarted the Python Kernel in about 5 seconds and closed the active kernel and all of the existing objects.
```

What follows is a stripped-down version of my code for testing this issue:

```
from fbprophet import Prophet
import pickle
 
pickle_in = open("/Users/swe03/Documents/ProductionCode/EgressModel/ads_mod.pickle","rb")
ads_mod = pickle.load(pickle_in)
 
## Start the modeling process
m = Prophet()
m.add_seasonality(name='hourly', period=1, fourier_order=30)
m.fit(ads_mod)
```

What follows is a screen shot of my Anaconda / Spyder after executing the test code above:
[image]

What follows is a conda list of my current installation.
Note:  This issue occurs in both fbprophet 0.5 and 0.7.1.

## Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0
appdirs                   1.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
applaunchservices         0.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
appnope                   0.1.2           py37hecd8cb5_1001
argcomplete               1.12.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
arrow                     0.13.1                   py37_0
astroid                   2.6.6            py37hecd8cb5_0
async_generator           1.10             py37h28b3542_0
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0
attrs                     21.2.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
autopep8                  1.5.7              pyhd3eb1b0_0
babel                     2.9.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
binaryornot               0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_1
black                     19.10b0                    py_0
bleach                    4.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
brotli                    1.0.9                h0d85af4_6    conda-forge
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h0d85af4_6    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py37h9ed2024_1003
ca-certificates           2021.10.26           hecd8cb5_2
cctools_osx-64            949.0.1             h6407bdd_22    conda-forge
certifi                   2021.10.8        py37hecd8cb5_0
cffi                      1.14.6           py37h2125817_0
chardet                   4.0.0           py37hecd8cb5_1003
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
clang                     10.0.1          default_hf57f61e_1    conda-forge
clang_osx-64              10.0.1              h05bbb7f_10    conda-forge
clangxx                   10.0.1          default_hf57f61e_1    conda-forge
clangxx_osx-64            10.0.1              h05bbb7f_10    conda-forge
click                     8.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
cloudpickle               2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
colorama                  0.4.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
compiler-rt               10.0.1               he6db49b_0    conda-forge
compiler-rt_osx-64        10.0.1               h033240e_0    conda-forge
convertdate               2.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cookiecutter              1.7.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
cryptography              35.0.0           py37h2fd3fbb_0
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cython                    0.29.24          py37hd8d24ac_1    conda-forge
dbus                      1.13.18              h18a8e69_0
debugpy                   1.5.1            py37he9d5cce_0
decorator                 5.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
diff-match-patch          20200713           pyhd3eb1b0_0
docutils                  0.18.1           py37hecd8cb5_2
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0
ephem                     4.1.1            py37h271585c_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.4.1                h23ab428_2
fbprophet                 0.7.1            py37hdadc0f0_0    conda-forge
flake8                    3.9.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
fonttools                 4.28.3           py37h271585c_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               h4cff582_1    conda-forge
gettext                   0.21.0               h7535e17_0
glib                      2.69.1               hdf23fa2_0
hijri-converter           2.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
holidays                  0.11.3.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
icu                       58.2                 h0a44026_3
idna                      3.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0
imagesize                 1.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
importlib-metadata        4.8.1            py37hecd8cb5_0
importlib_metadata        4.8.1                hd3eb1b0_0
inflection                0.5.1            py37hecd8cb5_0
intervaltree              3.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
ipykernel                 6.4.1            py37hecd8cb5_1
ipython                   7.29.0           py37h01d92e1_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
isort                     5.9.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jbig                      2.1               h0d85af4_2003    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.0           py37hecd8cb5_1
jinja2                    2.11.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
jinja2-time               0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
jpeg                      9d                   hbcb3906_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
jupyter_client            6.1.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_core              4.9.1            py37hecd8cb5_0
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
keyring                   23.1.0           py37hecd8cb5_0
kiwisolver                1.3.2            py37h737db71_1    conda-forge
korean_lunar_calendar     0.2.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
lazy-object-proxy         1.6.0            py37h9ed2024_0
lcms2                     2.12                 h577c468_0    conda-forge
ld64_osx-64               530                 hea264c1_17    conda-forge
ldid                      2.1.2                h6a69015_3    conda-forge
lerc                      2.2.1                h046ec9c_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           12_osx64_openblas    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h0d85af4_6    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h0d85af4_6    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h0d85af4_6    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0           12_osx64_openblas    conda-forge
libclang-cpp10            10.0.1          default_hf57f61e_1    conda-forge
libcxx                    12.0.0               h2f01273_0
libdeflate                1.7                  h35c211d_5    conda-forge
libffi                    3.3                  hb1e8313_2
libgfortran               5.0.0           9_3_0_h6c81a4c_23    conda-forge
libgfortran5              9.3.0               h6c81a4c_23    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.16                 h1de35cc_0
liblapack                 3.9.0           12_osx64_openblas    conda-forge
libllvm10                 10.0.1               h009f743_3    conda-forge
libllvm12                 12.0.1               hd011deb_2    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.18          openmp_h3351f45_0    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h7cec526_2    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h1de35cc_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h23ab428_0
libtiff                   4.3.0                h1167814_1    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.2.1                h0d85af4_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.12               hcdb78fc_0
llvm-openmp               12.0.1               hda6cdc1_1    conda-forge
llvm-tools                10.0.1               h1341992_3    conda-forge
lunarcalendar             0.0.9                      py_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                he49afe7_1    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0
matplotlib                3.5.0            py37hf985489_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.5.0            py37h3147e9e_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_2
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1
mistune                   0.8.4            py37h1de35cc_0
munkres                   1.1.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
mypy_extensions           0.4.3                    py37_0
nbclient                  0.5.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nbconvert                 6.1.0            py37hecd8cb5_0
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
ncurses                   6.3                  hca72f7f_2
nest-asyncio              1.5.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
numpy                     1.21.4           py37haefe36b_0    conda-forge
numpydoc                  1.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
olefile                   0.46               pyh9f0ad1d_1    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h6e7aa92_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1l               h9ed2024_0
packaging                 21.3               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    1.3.4            py37h5b83a90_1    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.3            py37hecd8cb5_1
parso                     0.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pathspec                  0.7.0                      py_0
pcre                      8.45                 h23ab428_0
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    8.3.2            py37h76dc067_0    conda-forge
pip                       21.2.2           py37hecd8cb5_0
pluggy                    1.0.0            py37hecd8cb5_0
poyo                      0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.20             pyhd3eb1b0_0
psutil                    5.8.0            py37h9ed2024_1
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
pycodestyle               2.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pydocstyle                6.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyflakes                  2.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pygments                  2.10.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pylint                    2.9.6            py37hecd8cb5_1
pyls-spyder               0.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pymeeus                   0.5.10             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 21.0.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
pyparsing                 3.0.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h655552a_2
pyrsistent                0.18.0           py37hca72f7f_0
pysocks                   1.7.1            py37hecd8cb5_0
pystan                    2.17.1.0        py37h1702cab_1003    conda-forge
python                    3.7.11               h88f2d9e_0
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-lsp-black          1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-lsp-jsonrpc        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-lsp-server         1.2.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-slugify            5.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python.app                3                py37hca72f7f_0
python_abi                3.7                     2_cp37m    conda-forge
pytz                      2021.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyyaml                    6.0              py37hca72f7f_1
pyzmq                     22.3.0           py37he9d5cce_2
qdarkstyle                3.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qstylizer                 0.1.10             pyhd3eb1b0_0
qt                        5.9.7                h468cd18_1
qtawesome                 1.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtconsole                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtpy                      1.10.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
readline                  8.1                  h9ed2024_0
regex                     2021.8.3         py37h9ed2024_0
requests                  2.26.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
rope                      0.21.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
rtree                     0.9.7            py37hecd8cb5_1
setuptools                58.0.4           py37hecd8cb5_0
sip                       4.19.8           py37h0a44026_0
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
snowballstemmer           2.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sortedcontainers          2.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinx                    1.8.5                    py37_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.2.4                      py_0
spyder                    5.1.5            py37hecd8cb5_1
spyder-kernels            2.1.3            py37hecd8cb5_0
sqlite                    3.36.0               hce871da_0
tapi                      1100.0.11            h9ce4665_0    conda-forge
testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
text-unidecode            1.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0
textdistance              4.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
three-merge               0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tinycss                   0.4             pyhd3eb1b0_1002
tk                        8.6.11               h7bc2e8c_0
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
tornado                   6.1              py37h271585c_2    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.62.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
typed-ast                 1.4.3            py37h9ed2024_1
typing-extensions         3.10.0.2             hd3eb1b0_0
typing_extensions         3.10.0.2           pyh06a4308_0
ujson                     4.0.2            py37h23ab428_0
unicodedata2              13.0.0.post2     py37h271585c_4    conda-forge
unidecode                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
urllib3                   1.26.7             pyhd3eb1b0_0
watchdog                  2.1.6            py37h999c104_0
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1
wheel                     0.37.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
whichcraft                0.6.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
wrapt                     1.12.1           py37h1de35cc_1
wurlitzer                 3.0.2            py37hecd8cb5_0
xz                        5.2.5                h1de35cc_0
yaml                      0.2.5                haf1e3a3_0
yapf                      0.31.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
zeromq                    4.3.4                h23ab428_0
zipp                      3.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3
zstd                      1.5.0                h582d3a0_0    conda-forge

Answer (score 1):

After further research I determined that a few approaches to this issue were well documented in https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1670.
I selected one approach and it worked.
Still not well understood why it happened to begin with, however.